# @ Symbol missing on Lubuntu installed on a mac

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, mac, macbook

For fun I installed Lubuntu on a MacBook 3,1 (2007, Intel Core 2 Duo).

Everything works, except I cannot find the @ symbol (writing this from my normal mac). I am using a German keyboard and usually alt-l does the job.

I changed multiple input methods, from english to several german ones. No luck.

I did 'dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration' but no luck there too.

Any more ideas how I can have the @ back?